# Difference between "greater than" and "greater then"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrases, pronunciation, dialects

What are there a difference between the following sentences?
They are pronounced the same or? Maybe it depends on the dialect?

A: Are you sure 'x' is "greater th**a**n" 'y'.
B: Are you sure 'x' is "greater th**e**n" 'y'.

I guess that 'A' should always be used, but wouldn't 'B' do just fine?
Would 'A' imply relative to size vs 'B' relative to time (since)?

Comment: No, "greater then" is simply a mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**than** is the word you use for comparisons in quantity ("3 is bigger than 2") or quality ("chocolate is better than vanilla")

**then** has multiple uses, but all of them relate to time, sequence, or conditionality:

- time: "See you then!", "Back then, there were no computers"
- sequence: "First I boil some water, then I add a teabag", "Then what happened?"
- conditionality: "If you give me a dollar, then I'll give you this apple."

So "greater then" is incorrect. Even native speakers often mess this up. In some dialects, **than** and **then** are pronounced the same, which contributes to the confusion.